# input type range not working on iscroll 5

Tags: javascript, html, iscroll

I have an input type range that doesn't work properly (doesn't slide) if I define an IScroll in the same container of the input.

I've added a preventDefaultException:{ tagName: /^(INPUT|TEXTAREA|BUTTON|SELECT|DIV|LABEL)$/ } but still not working.

Any idea how to solve?

**EDIT**: Adding eventPassthrough: 'horizontal' solved it.

Comment: You should put your answer below ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding eventPassthrough: 'horizontal' solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using this

preventDefaultException:{ tagName:/.*/ }

also comment out the css properties

```
  /*  -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  */
```